# Mac OS X Server v10.6.7: Client unable to start from a Mac OS X v10.6.7 NetRestore image

Tags: mac-osx

I have created a NetRestore image of a configured drive of Mac OS X v10.6.7. I had booted from the second partition and had created the image of the first partition using System Image Utility. Now the problem is that the client does not boot from the netboot server where the image is stored on.
Can someone help me?

Comment: We'll need more information to have any idea what's wrong.  First, what happens when you try to netboot?  How are you trying to select netboot?  What appears on screen as it tries to netboot?  Does the NetRestore volume appear in the Startup Disk preference pane when you boot from the local volume?

Answer (score 0):

it would seem that something is wrong with your network, are you able to boot up at all with a earth icon flashing?

what if you try booting to MAC OSX DVD then open the disk utility locate the image and restore to the partition you need.

also with your netboot, i sometimes need to stop and start and remove and re add the netboot image to my mac server.